What's the Content-Type if my ASP.NET Web API returns a GUID?
I've got a simple method that validates credentials and returns a GUID.
I've got the return type as ActionResult<Guid> but when I call it from the auto-generated Swagger page, it returns a 406. I can change the return type to ActionResult<string> and pass back sessionGuid.ToString() and it works fine, but from the point of view of an user of the API, it seems as though it's more informative to specify the exact return type. The generated swagger.json recognises it, for example:
"content": {
    "text/plain": {
        "schema": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "uuid"
        }
    }
}

and the Swagger contains a nice sample GUID instead of the generic word "string"

There doesn't seem to be a MIME type for a GUID. Is there a way of getting it to work?
[Consumes("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
[Produces("text/plain")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Guid> Authenticate([FromBody] Credentials credentials) {
  Guid sessionGuid;

  try {
    sessionGuid = _database.CreateApiSession(credentials);
  } catch (BaseRecordNotFoundException) {
    return Unauthorized();
  } catch (BaseInvalidDataException) {
    return Unauthorized();
  }

  return Ok(sessionGuid);
}


There is no mime type for a guid, unless you want to make your own (but why?). A Guid is just a 128 bit number. You're choosing to represent it as hex digits. What's wrong with text/plain or outputting a json object?

We don't have MIME types for every data type possible.
Your confusion arose from Swagger generating this information. But this is coming from Swagger scanning your actual code - that is why it's so good at constructing such suggestions/tips, etc. That's why it is great at.
But it does not reflect MIME types that could be used.
And from API user perspective - that is exactly why we have Swagger (or similair tools) - to be able to precisely tell what is the shape of the API, what are the definitions, etc.

return Ok(sessionGuid);

sessionGuid is not a string, therefor the HTTP response's MIME type will be application/json. If sessionGuid was a string, the HTTP responses's MIME type would be text/plain.
That's why you're getting a 406 - you're expecting (and your client is only allowing) text/plain content back, but that's not what the framework is delivering. Your attribute [Produces("text/plain")] is an incorrect assumption.

The answers given have pointed me in the right direction. I changed the return type to ActionResult<string> and returned sessionGuid.ToString() as before, but I also changed the ProducesResponseType attribute to [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Guid), StatusCodes.Status200OK)] which gives Swashbuckle enough information to format the Swagger UI with a an example GUID instead of "string"
[Consumes("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Guid), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
[Produces("text/plain")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<string> Authenticate([FromBody] Credentials credentials) {
  Guid sessionGuid;

  try {
    sessionGuid = _database.CreateApiSession(credentials);
  } catch (BaseRecordNotFoundException) {
    return Unauthorized();
  } catch (BaseInvalidDataException) {
    return Unauthorized();
  }

  return Ok(sessionGuid.ToString());
}


there isn't any type of Guid and
when you put your Guid inside OK() method it will converted to json by one value (because JSON doesn't have a Guid type) like :
{
  "4384e5d8-9748-4f99-898c-295c5c87449f"
}

so you only have 2 option which is make your own Mime or use string
in your scenario .net use json  response which is base on string

It's correct that Ok(Guid) will render to JSON, but it's not correct that the resulting payload will be a JSON object with a property called "value".
